# The selected file can’t be found by the algorithm. Any suggestions?

Tags: java, compression, bitrate

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? The selected file can’t be found and I honestly don’t know what to do. Is there any mistake in my file selection? I’m using the Jave2 Library btw.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ws.schild</groupId>
            <artifactId>jave-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(ChangerApplication.class, args);
        MultimediaObject multimediaObject = new MultimediaObject(new File("file.mp3"));
        File target = new File("file2.mp3");
        AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
        audio.setCodec("pcm_s16le");
        audio.setBitRate(16);
        audio.setChannels(1);
        audio.setSamplingRate(8000);
        EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
        attrs.setFormat("mp3");
        attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
        Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
        try {
            encoder.encode(multimediaObject, target, attrs);
            System.out.println("Successfully created");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Filetrace:

```
ws.schild.jave.EncoderException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\JUFERD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jave\ffmpeg-amd64-2.7.1.exe": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at ws.schild.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:640)
    at ws.schild.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:398)
    at ws.schild.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:363)
    at de.bitrate.changer.ChangerApplication.main(ChangerApplication.java:29)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\JUFERD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jave\ffmpeg-amd64-2.7.1.exe": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:590)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:449)
    at ws.schild.jave.FFMPEGExecutor.execute(FFMPEGExecutor.java:119)
    at ws.schild.jave.FFMPEGExecutor.execute(FFMPEGExecutor.java:141)
    at ws.schild.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:637)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:483)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: What's your working directory? Which file can't be found (you have two File objects)? It would help if you posted the stack trace and identified which line is causing the problem.

Comment: I am working in the project folder. The problem is in line 29 and the filetrace is under the Original Code.

Comment: 2/2 and it isn’t mentioned which file it is but I think it’s probably file.mp3

Comment: It looks like it cannot find ffmpeg executable. As per Jave docs : _JAVE is not pure Java: it acts as a wrapper around an ffmpeg executable.... You need a pre-compiled version of ffmpeg in order to run JAVE on your target machine._   So with default locator it tries to looks for this executable here "C:\Users\JUFERD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jave\ffmpeg-amd64-2.7.1.exe". So you need either to copy it there , or to follow Jave docs in section _Using an alternative ffmpeg executable_  [link](https://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php) to hookup your executable to library.

Comment: I tried what you attached to the link and I am thankful for your response but there ist a new problem. The encoding fails and the file is empty. Any idea how I can fix this?